# How to run a self timed method in a service Android?

Tags: android, multithreading

I am working on an App that runs a service that checks room noise level, in the activity is a handler that runs every 250ms but my problem is, it only runs when screen is active, according to my research a handler runs on UI thread, hence chances are its only running on UI thread that is why it only runs when am looking at it, could you please help me with a way I could run the below code :

```
    handler = new Handler();

    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        int count = 0;
        public void run() {

            // Get the volume from 0 to 255 in 'int'
            double volume = 10 * mSensor.getTheAmplitude() / 32768;
            volumeToSend = (int) volume;
            volumeVisual = "";

            for( int i=0; i<volumeToSend; i++){
                volumeVisual += "|";
                updateUI();

                Log.d("HandlerLooper", "Oscillating :" + count+1);
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 250); // amount of delay between every cycle of volume level detection + sending the data  out
        }
    };

    // Is this line necessary? --- YES IT IS, or else the loop never runs
    // this tells Java to run "r"
    handler.postDelayed(r, 250);
```

in my service without making run on UI thread but just within my service?

here is my full service code:

```
public class VolumeListerner extends Service {

private static String volumeVisual = "";
private static  int volumeToSend;
private Handler handler;
private SoundMeter mSensor;
/** interface for clients that bind */
IBinder mBinder;
/** indicates whether onRebind should be used */
boolean mAllowRebind;
/** The service is starting, due to a call to startService() */

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    soundLevelCheck();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}


private void soundLevelCheck()
{
    mSensor = new SoundMeter();
    try {
        mSensor.start();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sound sensor initiated.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    handler = new Handler();

    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        int count = 0;
        public void run() {

            // Get the volume from 0 to 255 in 'int'
            double volume = 10 * mSensor.getTheAmplitude() / 32768;
            volumeToSend = (int) volume;
            volumeVisual = "";

            for( int i=0; i<volumeToSend; i++){
                volumeVisual += "|";
                updateUI();

                Log.d("HandlerLooper", "Oscillating :" + count+1);
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 250); // amount of delay between every cycle of volume level detection + sending the data  out
        }
    };

    // Is this line necessary? --- YES IT IS, or else the loop never runs
    // this tells Java to run "r"
    handler.postDelayed(r, 250);
}



private void updateUI()
{


    Intent intent = new Intent( "UI_UPDATER" );
    intent.putExtra("VolumeBars", "Volume Bars: " +  String.valueOf(volumeVisual));
    intent.putExtra("volumeLevel","Volume Levels: " +  String.valueOf(volumeToSend));
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);

}
```

All help will be Appreciated Thank You in advance.

Comment: I think you have already posted this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Android `Service` will always run in the UI thread, except for an `IntentService`, which will create a worker thread for you.

Therefore when you create the `Handler` inside the service it will attach to the UI thread.

What I suggest is for you to use a `HandlerThread` which contains a looper that can be passed to the `Handler`. Example provided below.

```
HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("NoiceHandlerThread");
handlerThread.start();
Handler handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
```

Comment: will this work even when app is minimized? I used a service because it stays active even when the app is not on screen.

Comment: yes. you can use a service. then it will still run even if the app is not in the foreground.

Answer (score 1):

`postDelayed()` is not a great solution for a `Service`. As you note, it is tied to the main application thread, and usually we want services *not* doing work on the main application thread.

Use other standard Java timing mechanisms, [like `ScheduledExecutorService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).